# Zend URL POST security gap

Tags: security, url, zend-framework, post

I'm new with Zend framework and PHP, however nothing I've read has helped me to bridge a security gap we've discovered with the plugin POSTMAN on chrome.

Basically I can do a raw POST to a URL that retrieves info from the MySQL db,
to the likes of:

```
POST to foo.local/workspace/execute-task

[{"Contract":"f7f5d77a2fe0fda2df3a93xxxxa9b93","Packet":{},"Options":{}}]
```

This returns

```
[
    {
        "RequestId": 0,
        "Hash": "f7f5d77a2fe0fda2df3a93xxxxa9b93",
        "Status": "Success",
        "Message": "List retrieved.",
        "Data": []
    }
]
```

even after logging out. The session token generated on login has a lifetime of useonce, however its still possible to post once on the outside of the site

Because I'm still learning ZEND php, I'm hoping someone could give me a tip as to what to add to the specific module that calls up the list from the DB, if I'm being cryptic here it's for safety's sake.

Is there a quick fix that I could add to the module that returns the list?

I have excellent google skills, but it's hard if you're not sure what to google for (I've even come across some religious sites in my quest, true story) .

Let me know if I can add to this, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you post "normaly" from a form i would add CSRF Protection.

Comment: Do you mean, that you can perform request to 'execute-task' after logging out? You should fix your session mechanisms in order to prevent such behaviour. Do you really destroy session on logout?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Thank you for the response, im looking into that right now. -ArneRie the post is artificial using a plugin on chrome called POSTMAN, so the URL is entered and the raw post data, it returns the result as above. My lack of knowledge around the framework is costing me time to get to a solution quick :) however i will look into the CSRF protection you are talking about and the advice shukshin.ivan has given.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan, just to answer, yes, the execute task is responding after logout

Comment: @ElectroCute so, you have two problems: csrf and clear logging out.